# customize react full calendar title format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using React Fullcalendar, and I want to customize and change the sort of tiltle format

```
 <FullCalendar
                plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin]}
                headerToolbar={{
                  left: 'prev title next',
                  center: '',
                  right: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth,listWeek',
                }}
                buttonText={{
                  today:    'Today',
                  month:    'Month',
                  week:     'Week',
                  day:      'Day',
                  list:     'Agenda'
                }}
                views = {{
                  dayGridMonth: {
                    titleFormat: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
                  },

                  timeGridDay: {
                    titleFormat: {day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric', month: 'long'},
                  },

                  timeGridWeek: {
                    titleFormat: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long'},
                  }
                }}
                
                slotLabelFormat={e => `${e.date.hour <= 9 ? `0${e.date.hour}` : e.date.hour}:${e.date.minute <= 9 ? `0${e.date.minute}` : e.date.minute}`}
                eventTimeFormat={{
                  hour: '2-digit',
                  hour12: false,
                  minute: '2-digit',
                  meridiem: 'short'
                }}
                
                allDaySlot= {false}
                allDayText= 'all'
                
                initialView='dayGridMonth'
                aspectRatio={2}
                initialEvents={INITIAL_EVENTS}
                select={handleDateSelect}
                eventContent={renderEventContent}
                eventClick={handleEventClick}
                eventsSet={handleEvents}
              />
```

this is my code, inside of day view mode at the top of the calendar between the next and prev button text is like this: `August 15,2023`, I| want to change this part to `15 August 2023`.
Is there any way to customize this part?

I've tried titleFormat, but it doesn't change the position, it just change how the show